# C# Interop.Word - Bolding a Portion of a Document

Tags: c#, interop

I'm trying to make a helper function to bold portions of a Office.Interop.Word Document.  It accepts a Document, a string and attempts to bold based on if the string of text is found in the Document.  It does nothing to the text however.  As you can see, I even tried passing in the Document by reference to no avail.  Any suggestions?

```
public static void MakeBold(ref Document doc, string text)
        {
            Range range = doc.Range(0, 0);
            if (range.Find.Execute(text))
            {
                range.Font.Bold = 1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code instead:

```
public static void MakeBold(ref Document doc, string text)
{
    Range range = doc.Range(0, 0);
    if (range.Find.Execute(text))
    {
        range.Font.Bold = true;
    }
}
```

Hope that is enought to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, that did not work.  The Bold property wants an integer, not a Boolean...